# Handling multiple dependent requests in Redux-Saga - Handling Error

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

Given an array of offers I want to send many http request to the server for creating each of them. I am using redux-saga and I am struggling in making them sequential and dependent one to another.

Infact if just one of them fails I want the next ones to abort:

I tried this way

```
function* handleCreateOffers(action: ReturnType<typeof createOffers>) {
  console.log(action.payload)

  try {
    const responses = action.payload.offers.map(offer => {
      httpCreateOffer('/createOffer', offer)
        .then(result => result)
        .catch(err => {
          throw new Error('Socket Event Timeout')
        })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error && err.stack) {
      yield put(createOffersError(err.stack))
    } else {
      yield put(createOffersError('An unknown error occured.'))
    }
  }
}
```

However when I throw an error it doesn't seem to get to the catch statement, instead it continue to scroll the array

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function* handleCreateOffers(action: ReturnType<typeof createOffers>) {
  const offers = action.payload.offers.

  for (let i = 0; i < offers.length; i += 1) {
    try {
      const result = yield call(httpCreateOffer, '/createOffer', offers[i]);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error && err.stack) {
        yield put(createOffersError(err.stack))
      } else {
        yield put(createOffersError('An unknown error occured.'))
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Your error handling will be a bit different.  The important part is to `break` the loop.